# KO - Compare two items in a for loop?

Tags: knockout.js

I am displaying a list of data using knockout. This works fine.

```
<ul>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier1</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier1</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier1</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier2</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier2</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier2</li>
<ul>
```

There is one other requirement. Whenever the Tier changes, I have to add an additional class to li (just for the first row).

```
<ul>
    <li class="x">Title</li><li class="x">Tier1</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier1</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier1</li>
    <li class="x">Title</li><li class="x">Tier2</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier2</li>
    <li>Title</li><li>Tier2</li>
<ul>
```

Is this possible in KO? Inside the for loop, I have to access the previous item's tier and check that value against current item's tier.

Thanks.

Comment: how is this generated? what does your view model/view look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this calling a function in your view model directly within the foreach.  Simplest thing to do is to call it from the `css` binding and return a value indicating whether the class should be applied.

**Html View:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li  data-bind="css:{x: $parent.shouldApplyClass($data.tier(), false)}, text: title"></li>
        <li data-bind="css:{x: $parent.shouldApplyClass($data.tier(), true)}, text: tier"></li>
</div>
```

**View Model:**

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        {title: ko.observable("Title"), tier: ko.observable("Tier1")},
        {title: ko.observable("Title"), tier: ko.observable("Tier1")},
        {title: ko.observable("Title"), tier: ko.observable("Tier2")},
        {title: ko.observable("Title"), tier: ko.observable("Tier2")},
        {title: ko.observable("Title"), tier: ko.observable("Tier3")}
    ]);

    var lastTier;
    self.shouldApplyClass = function(tier, reset){
        if( tier != lastTier){
            if( reset){
                lastTier = tier;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[**See the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/RCVBb/2/)

Comment: Classic level checking :-)